# why my next js server immediately stops after i run it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, crash

I created a next app with create-next-app@latest. When I run npm run dev the server starts and then close/stops automaitcally.

It shows the following output:

```
> chljabhye@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- info Using wasm build of next-swc
```

And then it exits.

I tried reinstalling node. It didn't work. My current node version is 18.6.1 and I am using a system of 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Next.js requires a 64-bit architecture to run properly. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with 32-bit systems.

Comment: @trueThari Does this apply to all the versions of next?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js requires a 64-bit architecture to run properly. Unfortunately, it is not compatible with 32-bit systems.

You mentioned that you are using a system of 32-bit architecture, which could be the reason why the Next.js server is not starting correctly and automatically stops. Next.js has specific system requirements, and running it on a 32-bit system is not supported.

Comment: There is nothing on the official docs saying about this. The requirement is just node 16.8 or higher. [See here](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue before, and I resolved it by updating Node.js to the latest LTS version. You can follow this [article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version) for steps on updating Node.js. After updating, make sure to reinstall node_modules.
Running npm run dev again should resolve the server startup problem.